# How to get a click event in an iframe trigger an alert in parent frame

Tags: jquery

I have several embedded `iframes` on my page and I'm looking for a click event inside the `ifram`e to trigger an alert on the parent frame. (both iframe & parent frame are same domain).

iFrame HTML element (the iframe has a class of `class="iframe1"`:

```
<a class="button" href="#">Trigger Parent Frame Alert</a>
```

iFrame jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('.button').click(function() {
    window.parent.triggerAlert();
  });
});
```

Parent Frame jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function triggerAlert(){
    alert('iFrame button has been clicked');
  }
});
```

I'm thinking my parent frame function is incomplete - and not entirely sure the iframe can communicate with the parent DOM?

I have previously tried this alternative with no luck in the parent frame:

```
$('.iframe1').contents().find('.button').click(function () {
  alert("iFrame button has been clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make your function visible to the iframe you need to declare it as a member of the window object:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.triggerAlert = function (){
        alert('iFrame button has been clicked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You trigger alert function is in a closure.
try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 window.triggerAlert = function triggerAlert(){
    alert('iFrame button has been clicked');
  };
});
```