# Popping a modal with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following in an html file:

```
<div id='confirm'>
  <div class='header'><span>Stay Online</span></div>
  <div class='message'></div>
  <div class='buttons'>
    <div class='no simplemodal-close'>No</div><div class='yes'>Yes</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

which is a simplemodal from http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/

and I created a java script timer

```
if (iniTimer == 15){ 
  // call the Confirm class to launch the confirm box. 
} 
iniTimer = setTimeout("ClockCount()",1000);
```

in its own .js file and when the timer equals 15 secs I want it to pop this div from within javascript. Is this possible and if so could you please tell me how to do it?

Thank you very much,

Frank G.

Comment: what do you mean by "call this div"?

Comment: Well I have on an HTML page 

<div id="test"> 
code here...
</div>

Now this div is used to call a jquery function. I can call it if I use a button or hyper link but I need it to be called automatically once the timer hits 15 seconds. If test is call then it pops up a confirmation box. Understand?

Comment: But, what do you want to do with that div?  What action?

Comment: I still don't understand. When you say "code here" do you mean JavaScript code? Or are you saying you currently have used jQuery to assign a "click" handler so that when the div is clicked "something" happens, but now you want "something" to happen automatically from the timer? And why is this tagged as a CSS question? Show your code...

Comment: To help you understand more I am using this jquery http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/ modal and on the confirm demo if you click Demo is pops up a confirm box or you can call it like this <a href='#' class='test'>Demo</a> but I need javascript to call it automatically for me once the timer is up. And because it's not a function I don't know how to call a class id. Hope this helps. Thanks again!

Comment: Are you saying you want to click a link from JavaScript if the user hasn't clicked it themselves before the timer is up? What does that have to do with the div in your question? Please show your code.

Comment: This is the jquery code to call a confirmation box. 

<div id='confirm'>
    <div class='header'><span>Stay Online</span></div>
    <div class='message'></div>
        <div class='buttons'>
         <div class='no simplemodal-close'>No</div><div class='yes'>Yes</div>
        </div>
</div>

And you launch that box with a hyper link like this <a href='#' class='confirm'>Demo</a> I want javascript to launch this box for me without having a user click a button or hyper link to launch it.

Comment: Hello nnnnn no I am using the CONFIRM OVERRIDE on that page.

Comment: no I have a javascript timer which works fine but when the timer hits 15 seconds I want it to call this confirmation box.

if (iniTimer == 15){
 // call the Confirm class to launch the confirm box.
}

iniTimer = setTimeout("ClockCount()",1000);

Comment: I hope everyone understand what i'm looking to do. I'm sorry for the confusion. Please let me know if you have any more questions. Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have set up Something like

```
confirm("Stay on page?", function () {
   cnt = 15;
   tId = setInterval(ClockCount,1000);
});

var cnt=15,tId;    
function ClockCount() {
  cnt--;
  if (cnt<=0) {
    $("confirm").click();
  }
}

tId = setInterval(ClockCount,1000);
```

Comment: Hello Mplugjan,

That kinda works... when the timer hits 15 secs. It calls the confirm and it shows Stay Online and Yes and No but its not in the classes. Meaning its just showing as text. 

Here is the code i'm calling:
<!-- modal content -->
<div id='confirm'>
    <div class='header'><span>Stay Online</span></div>
    <div class='message'></div>
        <div class='buttons'>
         <div class='no simplemodal-close'>No</div><div class='yes'>Yes</div>
        </div>
</div>

Comment: See update - I assumed you needed to change the confirm to handle the timeout too

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's a little hard to understand the question, but I *think* that what you're asking is "I've got a DIV with an event (maybe a click?) bound on it; how do I trigger that event as if the user had done so after a set time?"

If so, you probably have something like:

```
<div id="test">bla bla...</div>
<script>
$("#test").click(doSomethingNifty);
window.setTimeout(function() {
    // I want to make $("#test") do something nifty after 15 seconds
}, 15 * 1000);
</script>
```

NOTE: You might not have written that $("#test").click() line; it might be in a library you are using.

If this is what you're looking for, there are several answers.  One is to just call the original method you hooked up:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    doSomethingNifty.call($("#test"))
}, 15 * 1000);
```

The more jQuery-like answer though is to use the trigger method:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    $("#test").trigger("click"); // or $("#test").click(); they mean the same
}, 15 * 1000);
```

The main benefit of using trigger option is that if you have multiple events hooked up to #test, it will trigger *all* of them (not just doSomethingNifty).

You can read more about trigger (or the shorter "click" form) on the jQuery site:

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

http://api.jquery.com/click/

So to finally bring this back around from an abstract answer to a tangible one, in your case I think you want to use:

```
$(".confirm").click();
```

inside your timeout handler.  Hope that helps.

Comment: You need to download confirm override from http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/ to give a proper answer.

Comment: Machine Ghost, that's IT YAAAAAA!! Thank you very much. If you wouldn't mind I have another question. I am basicly creating an auto logout box. If the user's idel for 15 sec then pop up the confirm box and say Hey Your Idea to long Stay Online? Yes, No This all works fine now but the problem i'm having now is that my app is using frames and say in frame A witch is 10px x 10px very small just to run the logout script in the background and then you have the main frame B for the app. When the box pops up it only pops up in the frame A.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to popup over frame A and B? Thanks again!

Comment: No way. You Will need to covert the frames to divs

Comment: Will I still be able to keep the frames using divs?

Comment: No, popup divs will not overlay frames

Comment: user1227427: Glad I could help.  If/when you consider mine the final answer, please do accept it (ie. click the checkmark next to it).  mplungjan: That's not entirely true. What user1227427 could do is put a function to do the confirm in his outermost frame, and then call it from his inner frame.  There's already a SO on this topic (it's with IFRAMEs and alerts, but FRAMEs/confirms are the same idea); see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277072/how-to-get-a-click-event-in-an-iframe-trigger-an-alert-in-parent-frame and post back if you have any questions.

Comment: mplungjan: When I answered this question it was (just) before your edit, and there was no mention of simplemodal.  It seems like you recognized it though, which is great (as I certainly wasn't familiar with it).  However, my answer was generic enough that it didn't matter what component's events were hooked up; I was just addressing the larger issue of triggering events manually, which seems to have worked for the OP.